# HTML Encode the content of input type text (TextBox) in client side (using Jquery etc)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using Ajax to post the comments of the website.

No the user can also write some scripts inside a textbox.

The problem is **I want to HTML encode it (REMOVE html tags,scripts ETC)**.

Means remove the html elements.

As far as now i make an unsuccessful try as:

```
 var textData = $("'" +  $('#textBox').val() + "'").text();
```

But this is a ridiculous attempt by me. Though it sometimes work but it MAY fail with special symbols etc.

Any help is this regard is deeply appreciated.

Thank You.

EDIT:

Whenever the user post the comment i send the comment to server and at the server side encode it and save it to DB and also on client side update my HTML. I dont want to get the encoded message back from the server

Comment: You should always do this sort of thing server-side - you can't guarantee that some cheeky hacker isn't just POSTing data to your server and bypassing all your client-side validation.

Comment: Not only should you do this server side, but you should do it at the last possible moment (i.e. immediately before you insert it into the HTML).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone else said, *please* don't do this. Solve it on the server.

However, the shortest way to just HTML encode whatever was send (that is, actually print out `<b>x</b>` is this:

```
var yourText = $('#textbox').val(); // or whatever
var yourTextHTML = $('<span></span>').text(yourText).html();
```

Comment: I need to use it like this var yourTextHTML = $('<span></span>').text(yourText).text(); Isnt it? to remove html etc

Comment: No, that will just return the tags in plain text. Using `.html(yourText).text()` would do what you're after *but that has the side-effect of possibly doing something you wanted to avoid* by parsing that HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't do this client-side. An attacker can just post a comment, intercept the request using a debugging tool such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com), modify it so it includes some forbidden characters - and you're [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS)ed.

It is highly recommended that you do this at the server instead. Just pass each comment through `htmlentities` in PHP (or the equivalent function for whatever server-side scripting language you're using) before writing it to the document, this will render [all XSS](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) attempts useless.

Comment: Whenever the user post the comment i send the comment to server and at the server side encode it and save it to DB and also on client side update my HTML. I dont want to get the encoded  message back from the server

Answer (score 0):

You should do the encoding when you are displaying the comments in a blog page and not at the client side that will helps to avoid XSS attacks and others. Encoding is not about removing html, script tags but it is about representing the angle brackets as character entity names.

For ex.

```
you have written a nice article<script></script>
```

after encoded

```
"you have written a nice article&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;"
```